How to get to /home when I am in /Users
I am new to using Linux so I am not sure how to fix this problem.
When I would use the pwd command it would show /Users/(my name).
However, I need to get to the home directory and can't figure out a way to get to /home/(my name).
Please help!

If you’re on macOS rather than Linux, then be aware that /Users is where macOS stores its home directories.

If you're logged in as your user, you can generally just type cd as a shortcut to go to your home folder
You can also do cd ~user to go to the home directory of user
